# How to Connect Oracle Db using Scala or Python in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, scala, pyspark

I have tried connecting Oracle DB in databricks with below code.

I have installed ojdbc14 driver in the databricks.

I'm getting an error to install Oracle client in Databricks. Could please help me to fix this issue.

```
CREATE TABLE NAV_TEST
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  dbtable 'Test_Table',
  driver 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
  user '***',
  password '*******',
  url 'jdbc:oracle:thin:*************')
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: This is the error i'm getting while running the above code.DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help

Comment: Then that is your issue, either you don't have the required libraries or your code cannot find them. If you are running in a distributed cluster with multiple machines, you will have to configure all to have it, I think.

Comment: Ok,Can you please help me how to install oracle client in databricks?

Comment: I have never done it, but I think following the instructions in the link that you posted could be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Martinarroyo.I have connected to oracle db,by following the link which i have posted earlier.